# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'B@9359e4d) '

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I'm trying to only retrieve "old" and "new" data from an MsSQL database trough pyspark jdbc.
With the goal to minimize the data retrieved. Lets take the simple case just retrieving old data

For that I retrieve the `max(TS)` where TS is of type Timestamp [aka rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

`current_ts = df.agg({"TS": "max"}).collect()[0]["max(TS)"] # becomes a python bytearray`

Then I try to push down a filter (so that it is executed in the DB) on that retrieved value
`TS <= current_ts` but that throws an exception

`.where(col('TS') <= lit(current_ts).cast(BinaryType()))`

This raises an exception:

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'B@9359e4d) '.**

When I look at the pushed filter I get this:

`PushedFilters: [*LessThanOrEqual(TS,[B@4c845753)]`

I already see problems in this print where the ) and ] are not in order.

I tried many things to make spark push down a legal SQL where clause, like casting stuff to different datatype than binary but either 2 things happen:

- it still does something in the DB with binary data that fails with the same exception
- the filter is not pushed down to the database and it works (but that means we retrieved all the data first from the DB which I was trying to avoid)

I also want to avoid writing my own sql query and abuse spark jdbc to create a new df based on that custom query.

Anyone know of what is happening and how to solve it?